# Склонение фамилии Комирняя

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Как склоняется женская фамилия Комирняя?

Comment: Ирина, Если знаете, как пишется мужской вариант этой фамилии, укажите его (предположительно, Комирний).

Comment: Информация из Интернета: https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Komirnyaya/skloneniye.html

Comment: @Sharon Это тот случай, когда исходная форма (м. р.) — Комирняя, но у меня есть подозрение, что м. р. здесь — Комирний (хотя они там дают ж.р. Комирная , но по-моему, Комирная — от Комирный)

Comment: Комирный, Комирная, Комирные -  об этой фамилии есть информация в Интернете, а о Комирняя, Комирний  - ничего не находится.

Comment: @Sharon См. мой ответ

Comment: Интересно, каково происхождение этой фамилии. Это не вариант от Камирный?

Comment: Носитель утверждает, что польское. Возможно, Комирний — польский аналог Камирного.

Answer (score 2):

Я спрашивал у носителей фамилии Комирняя. Ответ такой:
М. р.: Комирний - Комирнему - Комирнего
Ж. р.: Комирняя - Комирней - Комирнюю

Получается, эта фамилия склоняется как прилагательное (например, *синий*).

Из интернета:

> КРЕСТЬЯНСКО-ФЕРМЕРСКОЕ ХОЗЯЙСТВО КАМИРНЕЙ ЕВДОКИИ ГРИГОРЬЕВНЫ 
>   (https://sbis.ru/contragents/2312071191/231201090)

(Здесь, однако, А в первом слоге. )

> А еще мы хотим отметить работу главы Старокорсунского сельского округа Галины Комирней (https://krd.ru/gorodskaya-duma/struktura-gorodskoy-dumy/deputaty-gorodskoy-dumy-krasnodara-v-sozyva/strelnikov-georgiy-nikolaevich/rabota/ot-sebya-i-sosedey-/)